# How to childproof an iOS app by requiring "exit" button to be pushed multiple times before exit

Tags: ios, iphone, button

I'm quite new to xCode and am trying to build a simple children's app. I have a young child and have experience with her playing with some apps where it's too easy to exit the screen - either with the main iPhone button or by swiping/pushing a button to exit the app. I know there are workarounds to this through the settings on iPhone, however I want to make my app so it is more childproof upfront with regards to exiting the app too easily.

My app is structured with a main menu for parents to access the settings/help and has a play button to enter the kids zone. Once the play button is pressed, a new view controller comes up which is where I'd like to add the code to press the exit button multiple times in a row to get back to the main menu and to disable the iPhone's main button from exiting the app.

If anyone has a suggestion on how to go about this I'd sure appreciate your help!

Comment: Your app has absolutely no control over the behavior of the home button. It's either through guided access in settings or nothing. You cannot override this behavior.

Comment: There is the physical home button which you have no control over (and recently added is the "return to previous app" button which appears in some circumstances) but an app itself cannot dismiss itself or stop itself from being dismissed.

Comment: Also by Apple dev guidelines you can not change the behavior of Home/button... 10.5  Apps that alter the functions of standard switches, such as the Volume Up/Down and Ring/Silent switches, will be rejected

Answer (score 0):

Cool concept! I'll suggest you use a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Many subclasses of UIView accept gesture recognizers so you could simply do the following:

```
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(theMethodToExit))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 4
    self.theTappingButton.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

where `theMethodToExit` is the method you will call to exit from the app and `theTappingButton` is the UIView or UIView subclass.

I'm not sure if you can attach a gesture recognizer to a UIButton, but it might be worth trying. If not, you can mimic the the behavior of a UIButton with a UIView.

Unfortunately you won't be able to disable the home button from being pressed, though you can provide a tutorial to parents for how to lock the app on the screen.

Comment: Good idea in theory - except there is no functionality that theMethodToExit could call. An iOS app cannot exit itself. There are ways to do so, but recommended only for jailbroken or enterprise apps, as any App Store app doing so would be rejected.

Comment: @ThePumpingLama that part of the answer was to get back to the parent's settings within the app

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion with the TapGestureRecognizer - i'll certainly give that one a go!   As I read the comments on the home button it makes sense, but so sad for us parents who have kids that are very much attracted to that button - at least there are external solutions available :)